# How to obtain a single word from a string in C?

Tags: c, string

In order to complete a program I am working on, I have to be able to put pieces of a string into a stack for later use. For example, say I had this string:

"22 15 - 2 +"

Ideally, I first want to extract 22 from the string, place it in a separate, temporary string, and then manipulate it as I would like. Here is the code that I'm using which I think would work, but it is very over-complicated.

```
void evaluatePostfix(char *exp){
    stack *s = initStack();
    char *temp_str;
    char temp;
    int temp_len, val, a, b, i=0, j;
    int len = strlen(exp);

    while(len > 0){                      
        temp_str = malloc(sizeof(char)); //holds the string i am extracting
        j=0;                             //first index in temp_str
        temp = exp[i];                   //current value in exp, incremented later on the function
        temp_len = 1;                    //for reallocation purposes
        while(!isspace(temp)){           //if a white space is hit, the full value is already scanned
            if(ispunct(temp))            //punctuation will always be by itself
                break;                   //break if it is encountered
            temp_str = (char*)realloc(temp_str, temp_len+1); //or else reallocate the string to hold the new character
            temp_str[j] = temp;          //copy the character to the string
            temp_len++;                  //increment for the length of temp_str
            i++;                         //advance one value in exp
            j++;                         //advance one value in temp_str
            len--;                       //the number of characters left to scan is one less
            temp = exp[i];               //prepare for the next loop
        }                                //and so on, and so on...
    }                                    //more actions follow this, but are excluded
}
```

Like I said, overcomplicated. Is there a simpler way for me to extract this code? I can reliably depend upon there being white space between the values and characters I need to extract.

Comment: What happens to the `temp_str` after the while loop?  is it just memory leaked or did you expect to return it?

Comment: Why not using `strtok()` and storing the pointers to the original substrings. strtok works over the original string buffer, so no reallocation needed

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char));` o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are good to use library function, then `strtok` is for this

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char str[80] = "22 15 - 2 +";
   const char s[2] = " ";
   char *token;

   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(str, s);

   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL ) 
   {
      printf( " %s\n", token );

      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

[Reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)

---

The limitation of `strtok(char *str, const char *delim)` is that it can't work on multiple strings simultaneously as it maintains a static pointer to store the index till it has parsed (hence sufficient if playing with only one string at a time). The better and safer method is to use `strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **saveptr)` which explicitly takes a third pointer to save the parsed index.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char str[80] = "22 15 - 2 +";
   const char s[2] = " ";
   char *token, *saveptr;

   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok_r(str, s, &saveptr);

   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL ) 
   {
      printf( " %s\n", token );

      token = strtok_r(NULL, s, &saveptr);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Does this work for standard C then? (not sure if library functions means not standard C)

Comment: yeah its standard C library function.

Comment: **don't** use strtok, use the theadsafe strtok_r instead if you really _must_ go down that path.

Comment: What does that mean, it's not threadsafe? and what's the difference between strtok and strtok_r?

Comment: @Soren you are just confusing the OP, the complexity and content of question doesn't look like OP is doing some heavy project stuff. This function is sufficient for basic usage.

Comment: The difference is threadsafety -- strtok uses a global context, so if your code is running in a multi threaded environment the individual thread will step on each other toes and kill that global context -- resulting in wrong results or crashes.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar -- using non-thread safe functions should always be discuraged.

Comment: I am running a simple program to convert Infix notation into postfix notation and then solve said postfix notation. I don't believe I am using multi threading.

Comment: @Soren unless your are sure that somebody else is using it or not. Otherwise it is good to go. Thread safe handling has other compromises.

Comment: I am sure that this will not need thread safety, given that I've never learned about it before (I am a Sophmore in a Computer Science class).

Comment: @ShashwatKumar It should be emphasized that `strtok` is a notoriously bad function because, even without talking about thread safety, it contains hidden state depending on global or static variables. Depending on such antique functions is not a good way to learn C. The `strtok_r` function has been designed to use state passed as a parameter, which is the correct way to do so. If you at least add an example using `strtok_r`, which is really not that much more complicated, your answer will be more valuable.

Comment: @SirDarius Thanks for the suggestion, will update the answer.

Comment: `strtok_r` isn't included in the standard C library.

Comment: I can't use strtok_r then, because the specifications of my program are that they only use standard C. I'll just have to carefully write my function and hope it works correctly.

Comment: Why are you people suggesting that some one should use a function which doesn't seems to be a standard one...and you are down voting the below answer which does include a standard function?

Comment: It's just some confusion between the two. The argument is that strtok_r is better than strtok because it is more reliable and crashes less frequently. If I wasn't required to use standard C, I would use that function. But I am required, so I won't be using it. My problem has been solved, anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [strotk](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) function, i think it's what you'r looking for.

Comment: **don't** use strtok -- it is not threadsafe, and you will eventually kill somebody who tries to use your code

Comment: Strange, the first Answer got accepted because of strtok and this one got Down Voted. Really?